# Pause a method until it gets called again

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this method `run()` which executes a whole lot of other methods. In these sub-methods, there's a counter which increments with 1 in some sub-methods. When this counter reaches a given number `n`, the method `run()` should be paused for an undetermined time. When it's called again, it should start executing where it left before pausing.

Is this possible in Java?

**Edit**: some more information as asked by Andersoj

I tried to strip down my code a lot. This is a very basic example of what it looks like.

```
public void run(int n) {
   executeA();
}

public void executeA() {
   while (randomCondition) {
      executeB();
      counter++;
   }
   executeC();
   if (counter <= 100)
      executeD();
}
```

The code in `executeA()` should run until `counter` equals `n`. It doesn't matter until where it is executed, it should pause (this can happen anywhere in `executeA()`.

After a while, `run()` is called again, the code should resume where the thread previously stopped in `executeA()`.

Thanks again!

Comment: This sounds like a threading question, is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @GregFlynn, I've thought about threading but when the `run()` method is paused, other methods should still be able to be executed.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without threading, since you're describing a context switch

Comment: This sounds like something that might better be expressed in terms of tasks and executors.  Maybe you could put up some (skeleton?) code and conditions...

Comment: @andersoj, I added a very basic skeleton of the code

Answer (score 1):

If your stopping and resuming is based on a given condition, and assuming that the method would be woken up by some other thread that could make the condition change (none of the premises is clear in your question):

```
public void run() {
   synchronized(mutex){
      while(condition){
         try {
            mutex.wait();
         }catch(InterruptedException e) {//...}
      }
      goOn();
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can wait an arbitrary amount of time using `mutex.wait(waitTime)`.

Your other thread would wake the waiting thread when the condition changes or it will wake up again some time after the waiting time is up, in whose case the condition will be re-evaluated and it may enter into the waiting state again if the condition has not changed.

```
public void run() {
   synchronized(mutex){
     if(condition){
         mutex.notify();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: A condition determines when the thread should be paused. Another call of `run()` should start the thread again

Comment: @gieldl Can you elaborate on your statement please? Not sure what you are referring by "start the thread again", there is no way to re-start a thread in Java. If you refer to to resuming execution of a given thread, that will not happen until this thread is notified as shown in the second snippet of code.

Comment: Back again. Yes, I meant resuming execution of the thread started in `run()`.

Comment: So, `run()` is called, if the counter reaches `n`, the thread opened in `run()` should pause. After a while and executing some other methods, `run()` is called again, the thread previously opened in `run()` should continue where it paused. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: @gieldl Let me rephrase, you have two threads `t1` and `t2`. When `t1` hits the condition, it will wait, an arbitrary amount of time. Your thread `t2` executes and alters the original condition that made `t1` pause. Now `t2` can notify `t1` or overlook notification and let `t1` consume its waiting time. When `t2` wakes up (either by notification by `t2` or by consuming its waiting time), it re-tests the condition and if it has changed it resumes execution, otherwise, it enters in the waiting mode again, and again, by arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: @gieldl You might consider starting by [The Java Tutorial on Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)